# How to Write a Change Detector with Two Optionals in Functional Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type

Is there a functional way to write a change reporter for two optional variables?

The code is meant to detect value changes when moving from the value in **Optional A** to the value in **Optional B** with one quirk, that if **Optional B** is empty then we report a default value.

I want the following behavior:

```
    +------------+------------+---------+
    | Optional A | Optional B | Result  |
    +------------+------------+---------+
    | empty      | empty      | empty   |
    | empty      | y          | y       |
    | x          | empty      | default |
    | x          | y          | y       |
    | x          | x          | empty   |
    +------------+------------+---------+
```

I have a solution that looks like It should be simpler:

```
public Optional<String> reportChange(Optional<String> aOpt, Optional<String> bOpt) {
   if(aOpt.isPresent() && bOpt.isEmpty()) {
       return Optional.of(DEFAULT_VALUE);
   } else if (bOpt.isEmpty()){
       return Optional.empty();
   }
   return bOpt.flatMap(b -> {
       if (aOpt.isEmpty() || b.compareToIgnoreCase(aOpt.orElseThrow()) != 0) {
           return Optional.of(b);
       }
       return Optional.empty();
   });
}
```

What is the *functional-programming* way to write this?

Comment: Most will advise against using `Optional` to implement such logic (skipping the fact that you're using the type for method parameters for now). I think the advice should be heeded.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` flag values (specific values you check such as `"x"` and `"y"`)? Or do you use `x` and `y` to denote equal or different values for the parameters?

Comment: @ernest_k I have Optionals already so it made sense to resolve them as is, but you have a fair point. "x" and "y" are just place holders for values.

Comment: @Toaster  *"x" and "y" are just place holders for values* - so what does this line means? `x |  x | empty` - both optionals A and B are present and hold a particular value of `x`? Where does `x` come from?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko That line means that if A contains "x" and B contains the same value "x" the return an empty Optional as there was no change when transitioning from A to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to a simple conditional expression:

```
public Optional<String> reportChange(Optional<String> aOpt, Optional<String> bOpt) {
    return aOpt.equals(bOpt)
       ? Optional.empty()
       : Optional.of(bOpt.orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although such `Optional` usage isn't a good practice, this method does what required.

As I understood your logic `x` is an ***undesired value***, that can be present in the *optional A*. If *optional B* has is present and has the *same value* the result should be an *empty optional* (the last row in the table).

The condition eliminates this case. Otherwise, when *optional B* is present, it will be returned as a result.

If *optional B* is empty, then based on the presence of *optional A*, the result will be either an *empty optional* or `Optional.of(DEFAULT_VALUE)`.

```
public Optional<String> reportChange(Optional<String> a, Optional<String> b) {

    return a.isPresent() && b.isPresent() && a.get().equalsIgnoreCase(b.get()) ?
            Optional.empty() : 
            b.or(() -> a.isPresent() ? Optional.of(DEFAULT_VALUE) : Optional.empty());
}
```

**Important note:**

- Optional type is meant to be used only as return type. That was the only intention of the designers of Java when optional was introduced in the JDK. Usage of optional as a parameter is discouraged. The better option from the perspective of clean code is to unpack both optionals right "on the spot" (*in the code that obtains these values*), and then apply conditional logic.